# chatter groups are missing after sandbox refresh

Tags: chatter, sandbox-refresh

After I refresh sandbox (developer & full) i noticed that chatter groups are not showing up in Sandbox. do they not get copied from production ? I was expecting at least chatter groups to show up if not all the feeds in the group.
any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No when you create or refresh a Sandbox chatter group did not transfer. There are few Idea which you can upvote related to this.

[Chatter Groups and Profiles (but not data) in Sandbox Refreshes](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzKMAAY)

[Chatter Groups should be replicated for Sandboxes](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvr2AAA)

Comment: Thanks Tushar,  I've seen those Ideas and released they were raised few years ago so i was hoping to find a way or work around by now. I'll do some more research to see if i can find something useful.